# Spring boot static resource with ResourceHandler while deploying on tomcat

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, static-resource

I have followin project structure..

[image]

Now, I want load the static resources from resources/static/resources. I have tried to add following in my mvc configuration without any success.

```
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/resources/");
registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/resources/");
```

I want to access the resource directory under static as

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Any help or recommendation appreciated. Thanks.

Also tried following,

```
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
       registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/resources/");
       registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
       registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/resources/");
       registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
       registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
       registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/resources/");
       registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
       registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/resources/");
       registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/");
       registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");

registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/classes/static/");
       registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/classes/static/resources/");
       registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/resources/");
```

But does not work.

Comment: What templating view are u using? JSP, thymeleaf? and from where in your directory structure you want to access it?

Comment: Spring Boot serves the static folder by default. Doesn't it work for you? Maybe you override the default Boot behavior.

Comment: @DforTye I am using thymeleaf. I have login.html under resources/template (not under static folder) which uses the script tag I mentioned earlier.

Comment: @EvgeniDimitrov Yes. But does not seem to be working while deploying on standalone tomcat.

Comment: @Prashant When you deploy on standalone tomcat your application has a context. In other words the name of your war file is added to the url of the resources. Do you take that in account?

Comment: Yes. the context path is '/' so it should not be a problem. And also while I add registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/");
I am able to access the resource as   src="/static/resources/scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"  But my requirement is src="/resources/scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" @EvgeniDimitrov